# Pandas Style Object to Outlook HTML Body

Tags: python, pandas, outlook, pandas-styles

Several questions already exist on this topic but none clearly jump from `df.style` generation to Outlook.

The issues is: some `df` formatting is lost adding a styled df to an Outlook email body which is not lost saving the same `df as df.html` file.

Emailer Function

```
def Emailer(message, subject, recipient):
    import win32com.client as win32
    outlook = win32.Dispatch('outlook.application')
    mail = outlook.CreateItem(0)
    mail.To = recipient
    mail.Subject = subject
    mail.GetInspector
    print(mail.HTMLbody[:index + 1] + \
        message + mail.HTMLbody[index + 1:])
    mail.HTMLbody = mail.HTMLbody[:index + 1] + \
        message + mail.HTMLbody[index + 1:]

    mail.Display(True)
```

Dataframe styler

```
#format header
#format odd rows
#format hover
df_style=df.style.set_table_styles(
[{'selector': 'th',
    'props': [('background-color', '#4DAA21'),
               ('color', '#0F110D'),
               ('font-size','15')]},

 {'selector': 'tr:nth-of-type(odd)',
    'props': [('background-color', '#CBDEC3')]},
 
 {'selector': 'tr:hover',
    'props': [('background-color', '#7FE9F0')]},

]
)
```

Render the styled df

```
with open('DataFrame.html', 'w') as f:
    f.write(df_style.hide_index().render() )
    f.close

html = df_style.hide_index().render()
```

Call function

```
Emailer(html,Subject, "benjamin@ben.com")
```

I've tried using `to_html` but that is limited in formatting.

I've tried inspecting the `css` string that is generated but nothing was immediately apparent.

I've been back to the documentation and clearing the formatting is correct because the file is appears correctly formatted.

I think the issue is in grabbing and indexing the `mail.HTMLbody`.

Comment: possibly helps.  a technique I use with `to_html()` is where I append multiple parts followed by CSS.  For example: `with open(Path.cwd().joinpath(id).joinpath(fname), "w") as f:
    f.write("<h2>Search result</h2>")
    dfm.to_html(f, escape=False, index=False)
    f.write("<h2>Documents</h2>")
    dfph.to_html(f, escape=False, index=False)
    f.write("""<style>
        th {text-align: left;}
        h2,table {font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;}
        table {font-size: 0.9em;border-collapse: collapse;}
        </style>""")
`

Comment: I am sure I'm missing something but the formatting and CSS all works fine.I can see that in the html file that is saved down.
Looking at it a little further, I think it's an Outlook default that overrides the HTMLbody formatting that is included in the string passed into the function. I think the table formatting needs to prevent Outlook overriding the default formatting.

Comment: any updates after this? any solution?
i am also stuck here
here is my query:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70362091/python-styled-dataframe-to-email-using-win32com-outlook