# Python styled dataframe to email using win32com outlook

Tags: python, html, dataframe, outlook, win32com

Below is the output of my python code. dataframe is styled and converted to html file.

```
<style type="text/css">
#T_45521_row0_col3, #T_45521_row0_col4, #T_45521_row0_col5, #T_45521_row0_col6, #T_45521_row0_col8, #T_45521_row0_col9, #T_45521_row0_col10, #T_45521_row1_col3, #T_45521_row1_col4, #T_45521_row1_col5, #T_45521_row1_col6, #T_45521_row1_col8, #T_45521_row1_col9, #T_45521_row1_col10, #T_45521_row2_col3, #T_45521_row2_col4, #T_45521_row2_col5, #T_45521_row2_col6, #T_45521_row2_col8, #T_45521_row2_col9, #T_45521_row2_col10, #T_45521_row3_col3, #T_45521_row3_col4, #T_45521_row3_col5, #T_45521_row3_col6, #T_45521_row3_col8, #T_45521_row3_col9, #T_45521_row3_col10, #T_45521_row4_col3, #T_45521_row4_col4, #T_45521_row4_col5, #T_45521_row4_col6, #T_45521_row4_col8, #T_45521_row4_col9, #T_45521_row4_col10, #T_45521_row4_col11, #T_45521_row5_col3, #T_45521_row5_col4, #T_45521_row5_col5, #T_45521_row5_col6, #T_45521_row5_col8, #T_45521_row5_col9, #T_45521_row5_col10, #T_45521_row6_col3, #T_45521_row6_col4, #T_45521_row6_col5, #T_45521_row6_col6, #T_45521_row6_col8, #T_45521_row6_col9, #T_45521_row6_col10, #T_45521_row7_col3, #T_45521_row7_col4, #T_45521_row7_col5, #T_45521_row7_col6, #T_45521_row7_col8, #T_45521_row7_col9, #T_45521_row7_col10, #T_45521_row8_col3, #T_45521_row8_col4, #T_45521_row8_col5, #T_45521_row8_col6, #T_45521_row8_col8, #T_45521_row8_col9, #T_45521_row8_col10, #T_45521_row9_col3, #T_45521_row9_col4, #T_45521_row9_col5, #T_45521_row9_col6, #T_45521_row9_col8, #T_45521_row9_col9, #T_45521_row9_col10, #T_45521_row9_col11, #T_45521_row10_col3, #T_45521_row10_col4, #T_45521_row10_col5, #T_45521_row10_col6, #T_45521_row10_col8, #T_45521_row10_col9, #T_45521_row10_col10, #T_45521_row11_col3, #T_45521_row11_col4, #T_45521_row11_col5, #T_45521_row11_col6, #T_45521_row11_col8, #T_45521_row11_col9, #T_45521_row11_col10, #T_45521_row12_col3, #T_45521_row12_col4, #T_45521_row12_col5, #T_45521_row12_col6, #T_45521_row12_col8, #T_45521_row12_col9, #T_45521_row12_col10, #T_45521_row13_col3, #T_45521_row13_col4, #T_45521_row13_col5, #T_45521_row13_col6, #T_45521_row13_col8, #T_45521_row13_col9, #T_45521_row13_col10, #T_45521_row14_col3, #T_45521_row14_col4, #T_45521_row14_col5, #T_45521_row14_col6, #T_45521_row14_col8, #T_45521_row14_col9, #T_45521_row14_col10, #T_45521_row15_col3, #T_45521_row15_col4, #T_45521_row15_col5, #T_45521_row15_col6, #T_45521_row15_col8, #T_45521_row15_col9, #T_45521_row15_col10, #T_45521_row16_col3, #T_45521_row16_col4, #T_45521_row16_col5, #T_45521_row16_col6, #T_45521_row16_col8, #T_45521_row16_col9, #T_45521_row16_col10, #T_45521_row17_col3, #T_45521_row17_col4, #T_45521_row17_col5, #T_45521_row17_col6, #T_45521_row17_col8, #T_45521_row17_col9, #T_45521_row17_col10, #T_45521_row18_col3, #T_45521_row18_col4, #T_45521_row18_col5, #T_45521_row18_col6, #T_45521_row18_col8, #T_45521_row18_col9, #T_45521_row18_col10, #T_45521_row19_col3, #T_45521_row19_col4, #T_45521_row19_col5, #T_45521_row19_col6, #T_45521_row19_col8, #T_45521_row19_col9, #T_45521_row19_col10, #T_45521_row19_col11, #T_45521_row20_col3, #T_45521_row20_col4, #T_45521_row20_col5, #T_45521_row20_col6, #T_45521_row20_col8, #T_45521_row20_col9, #T_45521_row20_col10 {
  text-align: right;
  'border-spacing': '10px 50px';
}
#T_45521_row0_col7, #T_45521_row3_col7, #T_45521_row5_col7, #T_45521_row11_col7 {
  background: #0070c0;
  color: white;
  text-align: right;
}
#T_45521_row0_col11, #T_45521_row1_col11, #T_45521_row2_col11, #T_45521_row3_col11, #T_45521_row7_col11, #T_45521_row10_col11, #T_45521_row11_col11, #T_45521_row12_col11, #T_45521_row14_col11, #T_45521_row18_col11 {
  background: #c6efce;
  color: #006100;
  text-align: right;
}
#T_45521_row1_col7, #T_45521_row2_col7, #T_45521_row4_col7, #T_45521_row5_col11, #T_45521_row6_col7, #T_45521_row6_col11, #T_45521_row7_col7, #T_45521_row8_col7, #T_45521_row8_col11, #T_45521_row9_col7, #T_45521_row10_col7, #T_45521_row12_col7, #T_45521_row13_col7, #T_45521_row13_col11, #T_45521_row14_col7, #T_45521_row15_col7, #T_45521_row15_col11, #T_45521_row16_col7, #T_45521_row16_col11, #T_45521_row17_col7, #T_45521_row17_col11, #T_45521_row18_col7, #T_45521_row19_col7, #T_45521_row20_col7, #T_45521_row20_col11 {
  background: #ffbf00;
  text-align: right;
}
</style>
<table id="T_45521_" border="1" class="dataframe" style="border-collapse: collapse">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th class="col_heading level0 col0" >Date</th>
      <th class="col_heading level0 col1" >Scheme Name</th>
      <th class="col_heading level0 col2" >Scheme Code</th>
      <th class="col_heading level0 col3" >Equity Value</th>
      <th class="col_heading level0 col4" >Total AUM</th>
      <th class="col_heading level0 col5" >Equity %</th>
      <th class="col_heading level0 col6" >BM Allocation</th>
      <th class="col_heading level0 col7" >Effective %</th>
      <th class="col_heading level0 col8" >Large Cap</th>
      <th class="col_heading level0 col9" >Mid Cap</th>
      <th class="col_heading level0 col10" >Small Cap</th>
      <th class="col_heading level0 col11" >Mid+Small</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td id="T_45521_row0_col0" class="data row0 col0" >14-Dec-2021</td>
      <td id="T_45521_row0_col1" class="data row0 col1" >ANXX</td>
      <td id="T_45521_row0_col2" class="data row0 col2" >ANXX</td>
      <td id="T_45521_row0_col3" class="data row0 col3" >72</td>
      <td id="T_45521_row0_col4" class="data row0 col4" >1250</td>
      <td id="T_45521_row0_col5" class="data row0 col5" >5.74</td>
      <td id="T_45521_row0_col6" class="data row0 col6" >0</td>
      <td id="T_45521_row0_col7" class="data row0 col7" >0.00</td>
      <td id="T_45521_row0_col8" class="data row0 col8" >100</td>
      <td id="T_45521_row0_col9" class="data row0 col9" >0</td>
      <td id="T_45521_row0_col10" class="data row0 col10" >0</td>
      <td id="T_45521_row0_col11" class="data row0 col11" >0.34</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td id="T_45521_row1_col0" class="data row1 col0" >14-Dec-2021</td>
      <td id="T_45521_row1_col1" class="data row1 col1" >Group Gratuity Balanced Fund</td>
      <td id="T_45521_row1_col2" class="data row1 col2" >BALFND</td>
      <td id="T_45521_row1_col3" class="data row1 col3" >12</td>
      <td id="T_45521_row1_col4" class="data row1 col4" >50</td>
      <td id="T_45521_row1_col5" class="data row1 col5" >24.49</td>
      <td id="T_45521_row1_col6" class="data row1 col6" >25</td>
      <td id="T_45521_row1_col7" class="data row1 col7" >97.94</td>
      <td id="T_45521_row1_col8" class="data row1 col8" >85</td>
      <td id="T_45521_row1_col9" class="data row1 col9" >12</td>
      <td id="T_45521_row1_col10" class="data row1 col10" >3</td>
      <td id="T_45521_row1_col11" class="data row1 col11" >15.29</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td id="T_45521_row2_col0" class="data row2 col0" >14-Dec-2021</td>
      <td id="T_45521_row2_col1" class="data row2 col1" >Group Gratuity Growth Fund</td>
      <td id="T_45521_row2_col2" class="data row2 col2" >GRWFND</td>
      <td id="T_45521_row2_col3" class="data row2 col3" >13</td>
      <td id="T_45521_row2_col4" class="data row2 col4" >27</td>
      <td id="T_45521_row2_col5" class="data row2 col5" >48.32</td>
      <td id="T_45521_row2_col6" class="data row2 col6" >50</td>
      <td id="T_45521_row2_col7" class="data row2 col7" >96.64</td>
      <td id="T_45521_row2_col8" class="data row2 col8" >86</td>
      <td id="T_45521_row2_col9" class="data row2 col9" >11</td>
      <td id="T_45521_row2_col10" class="data row2 col10" >3</td>
      <td id="T_45521_row2_col11" class="data row2 col11" >13.96</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td id="T_45521_row3_col0" class="data row3 col0" >14-Dec-2021</td>
      <td id="T_45521_row3_col1" class="data row3 col1" >PNUV</td>
      <td id="T_45521_row3_col2" class="data row3 col2" >PNUV</td>
      <td id="T_45521_row3_col3" class="data row3 col3" >3</td>
      <td id="T_45521_row3_col4" class="data row3 col4" >9</td>
      <td id="T_45521_row3_col5" class="data row3 col5" >32.45</td>
      <td id="T_45521_row3_col6" class="data row3 col6" >0</td>
      <td id="T_45521_row3_col7" class="data row3 col7" >0.00</td>
      <td id="T_45521_row3_col8" class="data row3 col8" >100</td>
      <td id="T_45521_row3_col9" class="data row3 col9" >0</td>
      <td id="T_45521_row3_col10" class="data row3 col10" >0</td>
      <td id="T_45521_row3_col11" class="data row3 col11" >0.00</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td id="T_45521_row4_col0" class="data row4 col0" >14-Dec-2021</td>
      <td id="T_45521_row4_col1" class="data row4 col1" >Par Fund</td>
      <td id="T_45521_row4_col2" class="data row4 col2" >PPXX</td>
      <td id="T_45521_row4_col3" class="data row4 col3" >7595</td>
      <td id="T_45521_row4_col4" class="data row4 col4" >51493</td>
      <td id="T_45521_row4_col5" class="data row4 col5" >14.75</td>
      <td id="T_45521_row4_col6" class="data row4 col6" >15</td>
      <td id="T_45521_row4_col7" class="data row4 col7" >98.34</td>
      <td id="T_45521_row4_col8" class="data row4 col8" >78</td>
      <td id="T_45521_row4_col9" class="data row4 col9" >13</td>
      <td id="T_45521_row4_col10" class="data row4 col10" >4</td>
      <td id="T_45521_row4_col11" class="data row4 col11" >16.85</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td id="T_45521_row5_col0" class="data row5 col0" >14-Dec-2021</td>
      <td id="T_45521_row5_col1" class="data row5 col1" >Share Holders Fund</td>
      <td id="T_45521_row5_col2" class="data row5 col2" >SXXX</td>
      <td id="T_45521_row5_col3" class="data row5 col3" >27</td>
      <td id="T_45521_row5_col4" class="data row5 col4" >3258</td>
      <td id="T_45521_row5_col5" class="data row5 col5" >0.83</td>
      <td id="T_45521_row5_col6" class="data row5 col6" >0</td>
      <td id="T_45521_row5_col7" class="data row5 col7" >0.00</td>
      <td id="T_45521_row5_col8" class="data row5 col8" >0</td>
      <td id="T_45521_row5_col9" class="data row5 col9" >76</td>
      <td id="T_45521_row5_col10" class="data row5 col10" >24</td>
      <td id="T_45521_row5_col11" class="data row5 col11" >100.00</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td id="T_45521_row6_col0" class="data row6 col0" >14-Dec-2021</td>
      <td id="T_45521_row6_col1" class="data row6 col1" >Life Balanced Fund</td>
      <td id="T_45521_row6_col2" class="data row6 col2" >UEBAL</td>
      <td id="T_45521_row6_col3" class="data row6 col3" >1159</td>
      <td id="T_45521_row6_col4" class="data row6 col4" >3453</td>
      <td id="T_45521_row6_col5" class="data row6 col5" >33.55</td>
      <td id="T_45521_row6_col6" class="data row6 col6" >30</td>
      <td id="T_45521_row6_col7" class="data row6 col7" >111.84</td>
      <td id="T_45521_row6_col8" class="data row6 col8" >73</td>
      <td id="T_45521_row6_col9" class="data row6 col9" >18</td>
      <td id="T_45521_row6_col10" class="data row6 col10" >8</td>
      <td id="T_45521_row6_col11" class="data row6 col11" >26.61</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td id="T_45521_row7_col0" class="data row7 col0" >14-Dec-2021</td>
      <td id="T_45521_row7_col1" class="data row7 col1" >Life Conservative Fund</td>
      <td id="T_45521_row7_col2" class="data row7 col2" >UECON</td>
      <td id="T_45521_row7_col3" class="data row7 col3" >26</td>
      <td id="T_45521_row7_col4" class="data row7 col4" >260</td>
      <td id="T_45521_row7_col5" class="data row7 col5" >9.82</td>
      <td id="T_45521_row7_col6" class="data row7 col6" >10</td>
      <td id="T_45521_row7_col7" class="data row7 col7" >98.15</td>
      <td id="T_45521_row7_col8" class="data row7 col8" >85</td>
      <td id="T_45521_row7_col9" class="data row7 col9" >12</td>
      <td id="T_45521_row7_col10" class="data row7 col10" >3</td>
      <td id="T_45521_row7_col11" class="data row7 col11" >15.27</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td id="T_45521_row8_col0" class="data row8 col0" >14-Dec-2021</td>
      <td id="T_45521_row8_col1" class="data row8 col1" >Diversified Equity Fund</td>
      <td id="T_45521_row8_col2" class="data row8 col2" >UEDE1</td>
      <td id="T_45521_row8_col3" class="data row8 col3" >584</td>
      <td id="T_45521_row8_col4" class="data row8 col4" >602</td>
      <td id="T_45521_row8_col5" class="data row8 col5" >96.95</td>
      <td id="T_45521_row8_col6" class="data row8 col6" >100</td>
      <td id="T_45521_row8_col7" class="data row8 col7" >96.95</td>
      <td id="T_45521_row8_col8" class="data row8 col8" >71</td>
      <td id="T_45521_row8_col9" class="data row8 col9" >24</td>
      <td id="T_45521_row8_col10" class="data row8 col10" >5</td>
      <td id="T_45521_row8_col11" class="data row8 col11" >29.48</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td id="T_45521_row9_col0" class="data row9 col0" >14-Dec-2021</td>
      <td id="T_45521_row9_col1" class="data row9 col1" >Dynamic Opportunity Fund</td>
      <td id="T_45521_row9_col2" class="data row9 col2" >UEDO1</td>
      <td id="T_45521_row9_col3" class="data row9 col3" >309</td>
      <td id="T_45521_row9_col4" class="data row9 col4" >607</td>
      <td id="T_45521_row9_col5" class="data row9 col5" >50.87</td>
      <td id="T_45521_row9_col6" class="data row9 col6" >50</td>
      <td id="T_45521_row9_col7" class="data row9 col7" >101.74</td>
      <td id="T_45521_row9_col8" class="data row9 col8" >82</td>
      <td id="T_45521_row9_col9" class="data row9 col9" >13</td>
      <td id="T_45521_row9_col10" class="data row9 col10" >6</td>
      <td id="T_45521_row9_col11" class="data row9 col11" >18.11</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td id="T_45521_row10_col0" class="data row10 col0" >14-Dec-2021</td>
      <td id="T_45521_row10_col1" class="data row10 col1" >Amsure Dynamic Fund</td>
      <td id="T_45521_row10_col2" class="data row10 col2" >UEGFD</td>
      <td id="T_45521_row10_col3" class="data row10 col3" >1</td>
      <td id="T_45521_row10_col4" class="data row10 col4" >5</td>
      <td id="T_45521_row10_col5" class="data row10 col5" >14.37</td>
      <td id="T_45521_row10_col6" class="data row10 col6" >15</td>
      <td id="T_45521_row10_col7" class="data row10 col7" >95.81</td>
      <td id="T_45521_row10_col8" class="data row10 col8" >85</td>
      <td id="T_45521_row10_col9" class="data row10 col9" >11</td>
      <td id="T_45521_row10_col10" class="data row10 col10" >3</td>
      <td id="T_45521_row10_col11" class="data row10 col11" >14.53</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td id="T_45521_row11_col0" class="data row11 col0" >14-Dec-2021</td>
      <td id="T_45521_row11_col1" class="data row11 col1" >Amsure Income Fund</td>
      <td id="T_45521_row11_col2" class="data row11 col2" >UEGFI</td>
      <td id="T_45521_row11_col3" class="data row11 col3" >0</td>
      <td id="T_45521_row11_col4" class="data row11 col4" >1</td>
      <td id="T_45521_row11_col5" class="data row11 col5" >4.28</td>
      <td id="T_45521_row11_col6" class="data row11 col6" >5</td>
      <td id="T_45521_row11_col7" class="data row11 col7" >85.68</td>
      <td id="T_45521_row11_col8" class="data row11 col8" >88</td>
      <td id="T_45521_row11_col9" class="data row11 col9" >9</td>
      <td id="T_45521_row11_col10" class="data row11 col10" >3</td>
      <td id="T_45521_row11_col11" class="data row11 col11" >11.94</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td id="T_45521_row12_col0" class="data row12 col0" >14-Dec-2021</td>
      <td id="T_45521_row12_col1" class="data row12 col1" >Life Growth Fund</td>
      <td id="T_45521_row12_col2" class="data row12 col2" >UEGRW</td>
      <td id="T_45521_row12_col3" class="data row12 col3" >4480</td>
      <td id="T_45521_row12_col4" class="data row12 col4" >8708</td>
      <td id="T_45521_row12_col5" class="data row12 col5" >51.45</td>
      <td id="T_45521_row12_col6" class="data row12 col6" >50</td>
      <td id="T_45521_row12_col7" class="data row12 col7" >102.90</td>
      <td id="T_45521_row12_col8" class="data row12 col8" >86</td>
      <td id="T_45521_row12_col9" class="data row12 col9" >11</td>
      <td id="T_45521_row12_col10" class="data row12 col10" >3</td>
      <td id="T_45521_row12_col11" class="data row12 col11" >13.51</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td id="T_45521_row13_col0" class="data row13 col0" >14-Dec-2021</td>
      <td id="T_45521_row13_col1" class="data row13 col1" >High Growth Fund</td>
      <td id="T_45521_row13_col2" class="data row13 col2" >UEHGW</td>
      <td id="T_45521_row13_col3" class="data row13 col3" >1325</td>
      <td id="T_45521_row13_col4" class="data row13 col4" >1356</td>
      <td id="T_45521_row13_col5" class="data row13 col5" >97.74</td>
      <td id="T_45521_row13_col6" class="data row13 col6" >100</td>
      <td id="T_45521_row13_col7" class="data row13 col7" >97.74</td>
      <td id="T_45521_row13_col8" class="data row13 col8" >18</td>
      <td id="T_45521_row13_col9" class="data row13 col9" >66</td>
      <td id="T_45521_row13_col10" class="data row13 col10" >17</td>
      <td id="T_45521_row13_col11" class="data row13 col11" >82.26</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td id="T_45521_row14_col0" class="data row14 col0" >14-Dec-2021</td>
      <td id="T_45521_row14_col1" class="data row14 col1" >Growth Super</td>
      <td id="T_45521_row14_col2" class="data row14 col2" >UEPEQ</td>
      <td id="T_45521_row14_col3" class="data row14 col3" >9834</td>
      <td id="T_45521_row14_col4" class="data row14 col4" >10086</td>
      <td id="T_45521_row14_col5" class="data row14 col5" >97.50</td>
      <td id="T_45521_row14_col6" class="data row14 col6" >100</td>
      <td id="T_45521_row14_col7" class="data row14 col7" >97.50</td>
      <td id="T_45521_row14_col8" class="data row14 col8" >90</td>
      <td id="T_45521_row14_col9" class="data row14 col9" >8</td>
      <td id="T_45521_row14_col10" class="data row14 col10" >2</td>
      <td id="T_45521_row14_col11" class="data row14 col11" >10.37</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td id="T_45521_row15_col0" class="data row15 col0" >14-Dec-2021</td>
      <td id="T_45521_row15_col1" class="data row15 col1" >Pension Preserver Fund</td>
      <td id="T_45521_row15_col2" class="data row15 col2" >UEPWA</td>
      <td id="T_45521_row15_col3" class="data row15 col3" >46</td>
      <td id="T_45521_row15_col4" class="data row15 col4" >286</td>
      <td id="T_45521_row15_col5" class="data row15 col5" >16.03</td>
      <td id="T_45521_row15_col6" class="data row15 col6" >15</td>
      <td id="T_45521_row15_col7" class="data row15 col7" >106.86</td>
      <td id="T_45521_row15_col8" class="data row15 col8" >75</td>
      <td id="T_45521_row15_col9" class="data row15 col9" >18</td>
      <td id="T_45521_row15_col10" class="data row15 col10" >6</td>
      <td id="T_45521_row15_col11" class="data row15 col11" >24.58</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td id="T_45521_row16_col0" class="data row16 col0" >14-Dec-2021</td>
      <td id="T_45521_row16_col1" class="data row16 col1" >Pension Maximiser Fund</td>
      <td id="T_45521_row16_col2" class="data row16 col2" >UEPWC</td>
      <td id="T_45521_row16_col3" class="data row16 col3" >358</td>
      <td id="T_45521_row16_col4" class="data row16 col4" >744</td>
      <td id="T_45521_row16_col5" class="data row16 col5" >48.08</td>
      <td id="T_45521_row16_col6" class="data row16 col6" >50</td>
      <td id="T_45521_row16_col7" class="data row16 col7" >96.16</td>
      <td id="T_45521_row16_col8" class="data row16 col8" >74</td>
      <td id="T_45521_row16_col9" class="data row16 col9" >21</td>
      <td id="T_45521_row16_col10" class="data row16 col10" >5</td>
      <td id="T_45521_row16_col11" class="data row16 col11" >25.94</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td id="T_45521_row17_col0" class="data row17 col0" >14-Dec-2021</td>
      <td id="T_45521_row17_col1" class="data row17 col1" >Pension Balanced Fund</td>
      <td id="T_45521_row17_col2" class="data row17 col2" >UPBAL</td>
      <td id="T_45521_row17_col3" class="data row17 col3" >33</td>
      <td id="T_45521_row17_col4" class="data row17 col4" >89</td>
      <td id="T_45521_row17_col5" class="data row17 col5" >36.66</td>
      <td id="T_45521_row17_col6" class="data row17 col6" >30</td>
      <td id="T_45521_row17_col7" class="data row17 col7" >122.21</td>
      <td id="T_45521_row17_col8" class="data row17 col8" >72</td>
      <td id="T_45521_row17_col9" class="data row17 col9" >21</td>
      <td id="T_45521_row17_col10" class="data row17 col10" >7</td>
      <td id="T_45521_row17_col11" class="data row17 col11" >28.32</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td id="T_45521_row18_col0" class="data row18 col0" >14-Dec-2021</td>
      <td id="T_45521_row18_col1" class="data row18 col1" >Pension Conservative Fund</td>
      <td id="T_45521_row18_col2" class="data row18 col2" >UPCON</td>
      <td id="T_45521_row18_col3" class="data row18 col3" >1</td>
      <td id="T_45521_row18_col4" class="data row18 col4" >9</td>
      <td id="T_45521_row18_col5" class="data row18 col5" >9.66</td>
      <td id="T_45521_row18_col6" class="data row18 col6" >10</td>
      <td id="T_45521_row18_col7" class="data row18 col7" >96.59</td>
      <td id="T_45521_row18_col8" class="data row18 col8" >86</td>
      <td id="T_45521_row18_col9" class="data row18 col9" >11</td>
      <td id="T_45521_row18_col10" class="data row18 col10" >3</td>
      <td id="T_45521_row18_col11" class="data row18 col11" >14.42</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td id="T_45521_row19_col0" class="data row19 col0" >14-Dec-2021</td>
      <td id="T_45521_row19_col1" class="data row19 col1" >Pension Growth Fund</td>
      <td id="T_45521_row19_col2" class="data row19 col2" >UPGRW</td>
      <td id="T_45521_row19_col3" class="data row19 col3" >197</td>
      <td id="T_45521_row19_col4" class="data row19 col4" >370</td>
      <td id="T_45521_row19_col5" class="data row19 col5" >53.15</td>
      <td id="T_45521_row19_col6" class="data row19 col6" >50</td>
      <td id="T_45521_row19_col7" class="data row19 col7" >106.31</td>
      <td id="T_45521_row19_col8" class="data row19 col8" >82</td>
      <td id="T_45521_row19_col9" class="data row19 col9" >13</td>
      <td id="T_45521_row19_col10" class="data row19 col10" >5</td>
      <td id="T_45521_row19_col11" class="data row19 col11" >17.52</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td id="T_45521_row20_col0" class="data row20 col0" >14-Dec-2021</td>
      <td id="T_45521_row20_col1" class="data row20 col1" >Pension Growth Super</td>
      <td id="T_45521_row20_col2" class="data row20 col2" >UPPEQ</td>
      <td id="T_45521_row20_col3" class="data row20 col3" >299</td>
      <td id="T_45521_row20_col4" class="data row20 col4" >301</td>
      <td id="T_45521_row20_col5" class="data row20 col5" >99.13</td>
      <td id="T_45521_row20_col6" class="data row20 col6" >100</td>
      <td id="T_45521_row20_col7" class="data row20 col7" >99.13</td>
      <td id="T_45521_row20_col8" class="data row20 col8" >76</td>
      <td id="T_45521_row20_col9" class="data row20 col9" >20</td>
      <td id="T_45521_row20_col10" class="data row20 col10" >4</td>
      <td id="T_45521_row20_col11" class="data row20 col11" >24.25</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

This file when opened in browser displays correctly with all the required formatting.

However when i try to attach the html file to outlook emailbody, the formatting is all lost when mail is received

Below is the code which reads the html and attaches to outlook and sends email.

```
mail = outlook.CreateItem(0)
mail.To = toaddress
mail.Subject = mailsubject
mail.BodyFormat=3
mail.Display()

inspector = outlook.ActiveInspector()
word_editor = inspector.WordEditor

report_file = open(emailbodyfile,encoding='utf8')
html = report_file.read()

mail.HTMLBody =  html# doc.Content


mail.Send()
print('email sent')
```

the above html content is taken from the file referred to by the variable: emailbodyfile
what is wrong here?

I have another code which generates html output (win32com used to save excel as html with formatting) which works fine

is it something to do with the html generated by `dataframe.to_html()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

resolved:

```
'border-spacing': '10px 50px';
```

above line in style section was causing the trouble :(

Answer (score 1):

First of all, make sure that you set the `HTMLBody` property to a well formed HTML string. Trying to assign a badly formatted HTML string may end up with a blank body.

Note, Outlook uses Word as an editor for message bodies. So, it applies its own rules the HTML markup. Read more about that in the [Word HTML and CSS Rendering Capabilities in Outlook](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/office-2007/aa338201(v=office.12)?redirectedfrom=MSDN) articles.